# Function / question about Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

$$f(x+iy) = \sin^2(x+y) + i\cos^2(x+y)$$

I have calculated

$$\frac{\partial u} {\partial x} = 2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)$$
$$\frac{\partial u} {\partial y} = 2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)$$
$$\frac{\partial v} {\partial x} = -2\cos(x+y)\sin(x+y)$$
$$\frac{\partial v} {\partial y} = -2\cos(x+y)\sin(x+y)$$

So we see that $\frac{\partial u} {\partial y}$ = -$\frac{\partial v} {\partial x}$ is already valid.

For the other CR equation it must hold
$\frac{\partial u} {\partial x}$ = $\frac{\partial v} {\partial y}$
But here we have

$$2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y) =^{!} - 2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)$$

Could I deduce from that they would only be valid if $x+y = 2\pi k$ or
$x+y = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$?

Would this be correct to say that the function would be nowhere holomorphic, because there is no neighborhood where it is complex differentiable only single points?

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: @JonathanPal: thank you very much for checking

Comment: @AnneBauval: thank you, corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not change your final statement, but
$2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)=- 2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)$ is not equivalent to "$x+y = 2\pi k$ or
$x+y = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$". It is equivalent to "$x+y = \pi k$ or
$x+y = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$", i.e. to
$$x+y\in\frac\pi2\Bbb Z.$$

Note that you could find this condition a little more quickly:
$$\begin{align}\overline\partial f(x+iy)=0&\iff\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0\\&\iff(1+i)(1-i)2\sin(x+y)\cos(x+y)=0\\&\iff\sin(2(x+y))=0\\&\iff2(x+y)\in\pi\Bbb Z.
\end{align}$$
In your conclusion, I wouldn't say "only single points" (I don't know what it means) but "no interior points".

Comment: Thank you very much